# Что означают треугольные скобки в С++

Tags: c++, синтаксис

Поясните пожалуйсте, что означают треугольные скобки в такой записи:

```
Iir::ChebyshevI::HighPass<order> f;
```

и в такой записи:

```
Iir::ChebyshevI::BandStop<4,Iir::DirectFormI> bs;
```

Comment: Прочитайте про `template`

Comment: В них находятся шаблонные аргументы, которые вы передаёте соответствующим шаблонам https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates

Comment: шаблон, он же template. В 2-х словах не опишешь - лучше читать.

Answer (score 2):

Угловые скобки используются для работы с шаблонами.

Шаблоны помогают абстрагироваться от конкретных типов при создании классов/методов/функций. Перед выполнением, по шаблону автоматические генерируется код, специализированный под указанные в <...> параметры.

1. `Iir::ChebyshevI::HighPass<order> f;`

Сгенерирует новый тип **HighPass**, работающий с типом **order**.

2. `Iir::ChebyshevI::BandStop<4,Iir::DirectFormI> bs;`

Сгенерирует новый тип **BandStop**, работающий с типом **DirectFormI** и константой **4**.

К примеру, сам шаблон класса BandStop мог бы выглядеть так:

```
template<size_t CONST_1, typename PAR_2> // аттрибуты шаблонного класса
class BandStop {
  int m_IntArray[CONST_1];
  PAR_2 m_Object;
}
```

Для выражения `Iir::ChebyshevI::BandStop<4,Iir::DirectFormI> bs;` будет сгенерирован новый тип, примерно такого вида.

```
class BandStop {
  int m_IntArray[4];
  Iir::DirectFormI m_Object;
}
```

Допустим я хочу сделать аналогичный тип, который будет работать с другими аргументами. Имея дело с шаблонным классом, не придется объявлять всё вручную.

Я напишу `Iir::ChebyshevI::BandStop<42,AnotherClass> bs;`, будет сгенерено примерно следующее:

```
class BandStop {
  int m_IntArray[42];
  AnotherClass m_Object;
}
```

Имена новых сгенерированных типов будут уникальны, соотносясь с переданными параметрами шаблона.

PS: код генерируется перед компиляцией и в проект, в качестве исходников, не попадает.

Answer (score -1):

Опишу в двух словах =)
Например если взять машину в качестве примера, то у разных машин есть общие понятия, такие как: наименование, максимальная скорость, количество дверей и т.д

Для этого можно описать класс шаблон

```
template <typename T>
class Car {
    T t;  // в этой переменной будет экземпляр той самой характеристики
public:
    // Общая функция для всех машин
    float getMaxSpeed() {
        return t.max_speed;
    }
};
```

Далее опишем классы характеристики машин:

```
class Volga {
public:
    float max_speed = 180;
};
    
class Moskviche {
public:
    float max_speed = 150;
};
```

Теперь можно создавать класс машины через шаблон:

```
Car<Volga> * volga = new Car<Volga>();
Car<Moskviche> * moskviche = new Car<Moskviche>();
```

Вот рабочий пример:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Car {
    T t;
public:
    float getMaxSpeed() {
        return t.max_speed;
    }
};

class Volga {
public:
    float max_speed = 180;
};

class Moskviche {
public:
    float max_speed = 150;
};


int main()
{
   Car<Volga> volga;
   Car<Moskviche> moskviche;

   std::cout << "volga max speed: " << volga.getMaxSpeed() << "\n";
   std::cout << "moskviche max speed: " << moskviche.getMaxSpeed() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: А указатели зачем?

Comment: а что в них плохого?

Comment: Ничего, просто в этом примере не вижу смысла их использовать